# Display News Posts by Day with Post Counter

Tags: posts

I am building a site client who makes anywhere from 20-50 news posts per day. I'd like to have a news feed where it shows the date / post count as an H3 and then list all the posts for that day underneath.

Example...

**TODAY (4 posts)**
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link

**YESTERDAY (6 posts)**
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link

**MONDAY, JUNE 22, 2015 (3 posts)**
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link
 - News Article Link

...I can't find info anywhere on Google. Hoping this is possible. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Justin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clever manipulation of your Loop code should prevent having to make numerous additional requests to the database. Proof of concept:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post'
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);

if ($qry->have_posts()) {
  $date = $count = 0;
  $content = '';
  while ($qry->have_posts()) {
    $qry->the_post();
    $tdate = mysql2date('Y-m-d',$post->post_date);
    if ($date != $tdate) {
      if ($date != 0) {
        echo $date.' ('.$count.' Posts)';
        echo '<br>';
        echo $content;
        echo '<br>'.str_repeat('-',50).'<br>';
      }
      $content = '';
      $count = 0;
      $date = $tdate;
    }
    $content .= '<br>'.get_the_title();
    $count++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, will get all posts from '$day' days before today

```
/*
 * Get all posts from a specific day
 *
 * $day = how many days before today
 *
 * usage:   posts_from_the_day() will show posts from today
 *          posts_from_the_day(1) will show posts from yesterday
 *          posts_from_the_day(30) will show posts from 30 days ago
 *
 */
function posts_from_the_day( $day = 0 ) {

    $now = date('U'); //Get current second time
    $desired = $now - ( $day * 86400 ); //86400 = seconds in a day

    $year = date('Y', $desired);
    $month = date('m', $desired);
    $day = date('n', $desired);

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'year' => $year,
        'monthnum' => $month,
        'day' => $day,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    if ($query->have_posts() ) {

        echo '<h3>'. date('L, F d, Y', $desired) . ' ('. $query->found_posts .') </h3>';

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            //do something

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is going to be very expensive to run, and you are going to repeat yourself a lot. Please see the [DRY principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: I agree! But I've made this code more in a easy-to-read and multi-purpouse way than top-notch performance and specific-focused way. But even with this function he can get high performance with cache and transient ;)